# Show that $I(y)=\int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dx$ exists

Tags: integration

Show that the Riemann Integral

$I(y)=\int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dx$

exists for $y\in(0,1]$.

---

$A=\int_0^1(\int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dx)dy$, $B=\int_0^1(\int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dy)dx$

Show that $A$ and $B$ exist and $A\neq B$.

---

Showing $A\neq B$ wasn't that difficult, it was just integration by parts, I got $A=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $B=\frac{1}{2}$. But I don't know how to show that these integrals exist. I was able to calculate them and they're continuous but I don't really believe that that's enough.
I do realize that $I(y)$ wouldn't exist if $y\in[0,1]$ because you'd divide by $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrand $\displaystyle x \mapsto \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}$ is continuous on the closed interval $[0,1]$ for $0 < y \leqslant 1$ and, therefore, $I(y)$ exists as a Riemann integral.

We also have $\displaystyle \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{-x}{(x+y)^2},$ which gives us for $y \in (0,1]$,

$$I(y) = \int_0^1\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dx = \left.\frac{-x}{(x+y)^2}\right|_0^1 = \frac{-1}{(1+y)^2}$$

Technically $I(0)$ does not exist since, when $y = 0$, the integrand $x^{-2}$ is not integrable on $[0,1]$ in any sense.  However, the value of $I$ at $y=0$ does not affect the Riemann integral  since $\{0\}$ is a set of measure zero.  We can extend $I|_{(0,1]}$ as a Riemann integrable function on $[0,1]$ so that we have existence of the iterated integral

$$ \int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\,dx\right)\,dy = \int_0^1 \frac{-1}{(1+y)^2}\, dy =  \frac{1}{2}$$

By a similar argument, the iterated integral with the order switched exists.

---

Since the iterated integrals are not equal it follows that the function

$$(x,y) \mapsto \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3},$$

is not absolutely (or Lebesgue) integrable over $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. Otherwise, the iterated integrals would have to be equal as a consequence of Fubini's theorem.